# Change an element itself with jquery or Raw javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, attributes, element

is there any way we can change an element itself with jQuery or basic Javascript. for example : we have an Html Tag as `<a href="mysite.com" title='titlevalue'>Link</a>`, can we replace it like this `<a href="mysite.com" data-title='titlevalue'>Link</a>`.

Yeah, we can do add/remove title/data-title attribute however we have quite a lot of links so it would be better if we can have such sort of things. Searched on Google and here but didn't find anything like  this, just changing the values of an attribute and add/remove of attributes.

Please Advice.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Also, I don't understand what you're asking. How is add/remove attribute not what you want?

Comment: And why wouldn't you do this when the markup is generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be done like that too:

```
$('a').attr('data-title', function () {
    return this.title
}).removeAttr('title');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the data title attribute to each anchor tag, by using the value in the title attribute, you can do something like this:

```
$("a").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("data-title", $(this).attr("title"));
    $(this).removeAttr("title");
});
```

Comment: watch out. If you just add data-title jQuery dont have title in its data (see my anwser). @ScottMermelstein If he change all it will just be my answer :p

Comment: Altered answer to remove title attribute

Answer (score 1):

That will change title to data-title in all a-Tags:

```
$("a").each(function() {
$(this).attr("data-title", $(this).attr("title"));
$(this).data("title", $(this).attr("title"));
$(this).removeAttr("title");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eC2cQ/

Comment: You can [**"chain"**](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp) all that together: `$(this).attr("data-title", $(this).attr("title")).data("title", $(this).attr("title")).removeAttr("title")`

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... without jQuery... (just because it's always nice to have that option)

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(i=0; i < el.length; i++) {
    el[i].setAttribute("data-title", el[i].getAttribute("title"));
    el[i].removeAttribute("title");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com), you could do the following:

// find each a tag with a title attribute

```
$( 'a[title]' ).each( function ( index, item ) {
  // cache your jQuery object
  var $item = $(item);

  // replace and remove the attributes
  $item.attr( 'data-title', $item.attr( 'title' ) );
  $item.removeAttr( 'title' );
});
```

Some points of note:

- if you want custom attributes on elements in **new** pages, you are
  better off changing your back-end process to create these new
  attributes. To expand on this: if you are hand-coding new pages,
  simply write out the new attributes; if you are using a server-side
  technology, use the templating system you're already using to write
  out these new attributes.
- your example is not good practice: title attributes are useful to
  many people and machines. Replacing them with data-title prevents
  a lot of standard tech from finding the information contained in them. There is extra
  meaning implied by data-attributes, that they are *extra*,
  application-specific information, and link titles are better used in
  the generic way.
- it's redundant: if you can read a
  data-attribute, you can also read a normal attribute.
- there will be other ways to do this without using jQuery, but it's a pretty typical library in use these days

Comment: Just addressing your last bullet: While jQuery is commonly used, yes, it is also commonly abused. By that, I mean there are many pages that load the 90kb jQuery library just to perform DOM calls (and some don't even load the compressed version, so >270kb). jQuery is an awesome library, but people shouldn't be advised to use it just to perform a couple basic DOM functions.